# Run an interactive bash subshell with initial commands without returning to the ("super") shell immediately

Tags: bash

I want to run a bash subshell, (1) run a few commands, (2) and then remain in that subshell to do as I please. I can do each of these individually:

1. Run command using `-c` flag:

   ```
   $> bash -c "ls; pwd; <other commands...>"
   ```

   however, it immediately returns to the "super" shell after the commands are executed. I can also just run an interactive subshell:
2. Start new `bash` process:

   ```
   $> bash
   ```

   and it won't exit the subshell until I say so explicitly... but I can't run any initial commands. The closest solution I've found is:

   ```
   $> bash -c "ls; pwd; <other commands>; exec bash"
   ```

   which works, but not the way I wanted to, as it runs the given commands in one subshell, and then opens a separate one for interaction.

I want to do this on a single line. Once I exit the subshell, I should return back to the regular "super"shell without incident. There must be a way~~

NB: What I am not asking...

1. not asking where to get a hold of the bash man page
2. not asking how to read initializing commands from a file... I know how to do this, it's not the solution I'm looking for
3. not interested in using tmux or gnu screen
4. not interested in giving context to this. I.e., the question is meant to be general, and not for any specific purpose
5. if possible, I want to avoid using workarounds that sort of accomplish what I want, but in a "dirty" way. I just want to do this on a single line. In particular, I don't want to do something like `xterm -e 'ls'`

Comment: I can imagine an Expect solution, but it's hardly the one-liner you want. In what way is the `exec bash` solution unsuitable for you?

Comment: @glennjackman sorry, I'm not familiar with the jargon. What is an "Expect solution"? Also, the `exec bash` solution involves two separate subshells. I want one continuous subshell.

Comment: The beauty of `exec` is that it *replaces* the first subshell with the second, so you're only left 1 shell below the parent. If your initialization commands set environment variables, they will exist in the exec'ed shell.

Comment: possible same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120426/invoke-bash-run-commands-inside-new-shell-then-give-control-back-to-user

Comment: i gave up, but i didn't see this mentioned here, so FWIW: `RUN_CONDITIONAL=true bash --login` and put your commands in .bash_profile or w/e.  no idea on the portability.

Comment: And the problem with `exec` is that you lose anything that's not passed down to subshells via the environment, such as non-exported variables, functions, aliases, ...

Comment: +1 for adding all these clarifications in the question, it heads off a lot of unhelpful replies

Comment: Did you find a satisfactory answer?

Comment: Using the temporary named pipes trick is the only thing that lets me set `trap` calls in the newly-spawned subshell, and then have them still present when the human user gets to type into the subshell.  Cheers!

Comment: Regarding your point #3. It's funny, I found your question while looking for the same thing, but I was looking for it specifically to use it inside screen :) I wanted to start  screen split in two, run two shells, and then run two docker containers inside. Then I want to be able to kill one of the containers, and quickly run it again, so I wanted to have it exit back to the shell, ready to re-run.

Answer (score 145):

This can be easily done with [temporary named pipes](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156):

```
bash --init-file <(echo "ls; pwd")
```

Credit for this answer goes to the comment from [Lie Ryan](https://serverfault.com/users/55408/lie-ryan). I found this really useful, and it's less noticeable in the comments, so I thought it should be its own answer.

Comment: This presumably means that `$HOME/.bashrc` is not executed though. It would have to be included from the temporary named pipe.

Comment: To clarify, something like this: `bash --init-file <(echo ". \"$HOME/.bashrc\"; ls; pwd")`

Comment: This is so gross but it does work.  I can't believe bash doesn't support this directly.

Comment: @Hubro, what is the purpose of the `.`  in the command? Without it, I get a "permission denied" on my `.bashrc`, but I don't understand why, and how the `.` fixes it.

Comment: @Gus, the `.` is a synonym for the `source` command: https://ss64.com/bash/source.html.

Comment: This does not seem to work on older versions of bash, I've tried it on bash v3.2.57 and although bash does start, the commands inside braces do not get executed.

Comment: Is there a way to make it work with user switching, such as `sudo bash --init-file <(echo "ls; pwd")` or `sudo -iu username bash --init-file <(echo "ls; pwd")`?

Comment: After running the above command as-is, I get: `-sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('`
This works: `echo "ls; pwd" > initfile ; bash --init-file initfile`

Comment: Thanks! I thought it'd be worth to mention that my issue was solved with this solution in combination with exec, i.e.: `bash -c "exec bash --init-file <(echo 'ls; pwd')"`

Comment: @FractalSpace - are you sure you were executing the command from a bash prompt? Looks like a tcsh error to me.

Comment: Seemingly, no matter how I do this, the shell exits immediately.  I'm trying to start a bash shell (from tcsh) that initializes an environment for a project that requires bash. I'd like to create an alias in tcsh that switches to bash, cd's to the project directory, and initializes that environment, but it seems the best I can do is enter bash, then use a bash alias to do it: so 2 commands instead of 1.

Comment: @hepcat72 I always use bash, sometimes dash but never tcsh. Also, I no longer see that error.

Comment: assumes you're starting the new bash shell from a bash shell. Use the answer below if you're not.

Comment: @Evan has a crucial comment that other commenters may have missed:  the `<(...)` syntax is parsed **by the same outer shell that's starting bash**, so if you're running some other shell intending to _launch_ bash, this won't work directly.  Either use ExpoBi's answer, or run bash _and then_ use this syntax.

Answer (score 21):

Try this instead:

```
$> bash -c "ls;pwd;other commands;$SHELL"
```

`$SHELL`  It makes the shell open in interactive mode, waiting for a close with `exit`.

Comment: FYI, this opens a new shell afterwards, so if any of the commands affect the current shell's state (e.g. sourcing a file) it might not work as expected

Comment: @ThiefMaster you can easily circumvent this behavior (if unwanted) wrapping the init command with a subshell:
`bash -c "(ls;pwd;other commands;);$SHELL"`

Comment: Nice tip, but only partly true, @gagallo7; environment variables are inherited "down only", and since that will be a child shell, the parent will not see any env var assignments. See comments on original question for use of exec to retain env vars (though it probably loses anything your comment would preserve).

Answer (score 19):

You can do this in a roundabout way with a temp file, although it will take two lines:

```
echo "ls; pwd" > initfile
bash --init-file initfile
```

Comment: For a nice effect you can make the temp file remove itself by including `rm $BASH_SOURCE` in it.

Comment: Eduardo, thank you. That's a nice solution, but... are you saying that this can't be done **without** having to fiddle with file I/O. There's obvious reasons why I would prefer to keep this as a self contained command, because the moment files come into the mix I'll have to start worrying about how to make random temp-files and then, as you mentioned, deleting them. It just requires so much more effort this way if I want to be rigorous. Hence the desire for a more minimalistic, elegant solution.

Comment: Use the mktemp utility to create a unique temp file.

Comment: @SABBATINILuca: I'm not saying anything like that. This is just a way, and `mktemp` does solve the temp file issue as @cjc pointed out. Bash *could* support reading the init commands from stdin, but as far as I can tell it doesn't. Specyfing `-` as init file and piping them half works, but Bash then exits (probably because it detected the pipeline). The elegant solution, IMHO, is to use exec.

Comment: Doesn't this also override your normal bash initialisation ? @SABBATINILuca what are you trying to achieve with this why do you need to spawn a shell auto run some commands and then keep that shell open?

Comment: @Lain, yes it would be slightly more complicated to run the original init ("rc") files alongside the few extra commands that I want to run at the beginning. This is why I consider Eduardo's solution, as solid as it is, to be just less than ideal. But like I said earlier, the question is posed as a hypothetical one. I think there ought to be a trivially straightforward way to do this with 3-5 extra characters, but already I count **at least** ~4 lines worth of work: making a temp file, echoing your commands into that file, running bash, removing that file, etc... Nevermind why I want to do it.

Comment: @EduardoIvanec thanks for the mktemp command, I had forgotten about it. Sorry to press you further (you've been very helpful), but how exactly do you suggest exec should be used? Do you mean as I had written it in my original post? Also, could you tell me why you think it would be the most elegant solution?

Comment: This is an old question, but Bash can create temporary named pipes by using the following syntax: bash --init-file <(echo "ls; pwd").

Answer (score 6):

Why not use native subshells?

```
$ ( ls; pwd; exec $BASH; )
bar     foo     howdy
/tmp/hello/
bash-4.4$ 
bash-4.4$ exit
$
```

Enclosing commands with parentheses makes bash spawn a subprocess to run these commands, so you can, for example, alter the environment without affecting parent shell. This is basically more readable equivalent to the `bash -c "ls; pwd; exec $BASH"`.

If that still looks verbose, there are two options. One is to have this snippet as a function:

```
$ run() { ( eval "$@"; exec $BASH; ) }
$ run 'ls; pwd;'
bar     foo     howdy
/tmp/hello/
bash-4.4$ exit
$ run 'ls;' 'pwd;'
bar     foo     howdy
/tmp/hello/
bash-4.4$ exit
$
```

Another is to make `exec $BASH` shorter:

```
$ R() { exec $BASH; }
$ ( ls; pwd; R )
bar     foo     howdy
/tmp/hello/
bash-4.4$ exit
$
```

I personally like `R` approach more, as there is no need to play with escaping strings.

Comment: I’m not sure if there are any caveeats using exec for the scenario the OP has in mind, but for me this is the far best solution proposed, because it uses plain bash commands without any string escaping issues.

Answer (score 5):

The "Expect solution" I was referring to is programming a bash shell with the [Expect programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect):

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
set init_commands [lindex $argv 0]
set bash_prompt {\$ $}              ;# adjust to suit your own prompt
spawn bash
expect -re $bash_prompt {send -- "$init_commands\r"}
interact
puts "exiting subshell"
```

You'd run that like: `./subshell.exp "ls; pwd"`

Comment: I guess this would have the advantage of registering the commands in the history too, am I wrong? Also I'm curious if bashrc/profile is executed in this case?

Comment: Confirmed that this allow you to put commands in the history, which the other solutions don't.  This is great for starting a process in a .screenrc file -- if you exit the started process, you don't close the screen window.

Answer (score 5):

What you need is to execute a startup script, then proceed with the interactive session.

The default startup script is `~/.bashrc`, another script could be given with the `--init-file` option.  If you simply pass an `--init-file` option, your script would *replace* the default, rather than *augment* it.

The solution is to pass, using the `<(...)` syntax, a temporary script that sources the default `~/.bashrc` followed by any other commands:

```sh
bash --init-file <(echo ". ~/.bashrc; ls; pwd; ### other commands... ###")
```

Answer (score 1):

If `sudo -E bash` does not work, I use the following, which has met my expectations so far:

```
sudo HOME=$HOME bash --rcfile $HOME/.bashrc
```

I set HOME=$HOME because I want my new session to have HOME set to my user's HOME, rather than root's HOME, which happens by default on some systems.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation here to comment yet, but I think the various solutions with `bash`'s `--rcfile` (aka `--init-file`) are the most practical.

For a POSIX-compatible solution, you could also try something like

```
sh -si < my_init_file
```

where `my_init_file` terminates with

```
exec </dev/tty
```

which connects `stdin` to the terminal.

You could even try

```
sh -i -c'my startup commands; exec </dev/tty'
```

Note that making the shell interactive (with `-i`) means that certain errors are treated more leniently.

Answer (score 0):

less elegant than `--init-file`, but perhaps more instrumentable:

```
fn(){
    echo 'hello from exported function'
}

while read -a commands
do
    eval ${commands[@]}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I accomplish basically the same thing by just using a script, typically for the purpose of setting environment variables for use in a specific project directory;

```
$ cat shell.sh
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=$PWD/bin:$PATH
export USERNAME=foo
export PASSWORD=bar
export DB_SERVER=http://localhost:6001
bash

$ echo ${USERNAME:-none}
none

$ ./shell.sh

$ echo $USERNAME
foo
```

This drops you into an interactive `bash` shell after all the environment adjustments are made; you can update this script with the relevant other commands you want to run.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ bash --init-file <(echo 'ls; pwd')
$ bash --rcfile <(echo 'ls; pwd')
```

In case you can't use process substitution:

```
$ cat script
ls; pwd
$ bash --init-file script
```

With `sh` (`dash`, `busybox`):

```
$ ENV=script sh
```

Or:

```
$ bash -c 'ls; pwd; exec bash'
$ sh -c 'ls; pwd; exec sh'
```