# Running detached screen session but without termination in the same bash

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-screen

Here are *already many questions* like this, but every one recommends (a variant of) the following solution:

```
screen -dmS somename bash -c "/path/to/script; bash -l"
```

e.g. when the `script` ends, run an new `bash`.

Unfortunately, this isn't works for me, because

- the `script` uses the $BASHPID variable for something
- the `script` runs runs forever, e.g. need terminate it with CTRL-C
- and after the termination *i must* have the *same* shell as runs the `script` (same `$BASHPID`)

So, the question is:

- How to start the `screen` in detached mode (e.g. at boot) - normally this is done by the `-dm`
- it must start the shell

  - best, if it can start it as "login" shell, e.g. what reads my `.profile`, but this can be overcome with the `source ~/.profile` in the `script` itself
  - the `script` start some other (binary) program what will run till CTRL-C
- and after the termination of the `script` I must get the same `bash` (with the same `$BASHPID` (because need run another scripts what's depends on it)

In short need simulate the following interactive work:

- start `screen`
- `echo $BASHPID`
- run-some-commands inside the screen (the last one runs until CTRL-C) - e.g. run the `/path/to/script`
- detach (ctrl-a d)

After the above, later, I can do

- reattach (`screen -ARR`)
- CTRL-C
- and can continue... with the same
- `echo $BASHPID` #will produce the same as above

Any idea? (thinking about the `-X` but it not works, somewhere i probably making a mistake)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that
[the answer here](https://serverfault.com/a/586272/6491)
is for your use case. In short:

```
bash --init-file <(echo "yourcommand")
```

Comment: Trying the above as: `screen -L -dmS name bash --init-file <(echo "pwd;ls") (note the `-L` logging) i got in the `screenlog.0` the following: `bash: /dev/fd/63: Bad file descriptor`, and the commands aren't executed.(The child doesn't got the parent's redirection - the redirection is processed by the screen itself). Anyway, upvoting and accepting this, because it pointed me to the solution. `--init-file /real/file/with/bash/commands` works nicely. Thank you.