# Convenient date/time stamping console interaction e.g. using shell aliases?

Tags: bash, bashrc

So, I often find that I really want to know when I started a process (or script) after I discovered that it was taking ages.. meaning I couldn't pre-pend date before and after it on the command line (without interrupting something I now know takes ages).. and then the process may finish while I'm away from the terminal.

That got me thinking - is it possible to contort shell aliasing such that by default a 'date' is invoked before and after every command line entry? It would be super-useful to sometimes be able to scroll back in the terminal and get a feel of how long stuff took.

Do other people have clever ways of addressing this - I'm sure it's a common enough scenario.

In terms of solutions with this approach, I'm guessing it's related a bit to this Q.
[Run an interactive bash subshell with initial commands without returning to the ("super") shell immediately](https://serverfault.com/questions/368054/run-an-interactive-bash-subshell-with-initial-commands-without-returning-to-the)

where it's clear you can prepend commands.. but that's only a part of the solution. Perhaps pre-pending and then getting the shell prompt to show current time would be a fairly neat solution?

Thoughts?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26797

Comment: excellent spot - very useful pointer to `ts` and `gnomon` as ways of time stamping different points output comes from a process. Gnomon looks particularly fun if you are wanting time deltas in a process. Mostly people are deprecating `date` as too slow and pointing out that it's possible to use much faster `printf` function within modern versions of bash.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply modify your shell prompt `PS1` variable to show current timestamp. One of the following can be used:

```
\t     the current time in 24-hour HH:MM:SS format
\T     the current time in 12-hour HH:MM:SS format
\@     the current time in 12-hour am/pm format
\A     the current time in 24-hour HH:MM format
```

You can find these with other options in `man bash`. Edit your `.bashrc` file to modify `PS1` as desired.

You can then determine when any command is executed. Of course, if you stay idle for a long time before hitting enter, you will not get accurate time.

**Edit:** Another possibility is to use `ts` utility to show how your script is progressing. Execute your script as:

```
$ /path/to/script | ts
```

Each echo statement will be displayed with a timestamp.

Comment: there's useful material on this at: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35777/how-to-change-the-prompt-in-linux and there is also a handy `.bashrc` generator available at http://bashrcgenerator.com/ One thing worth noting though is there are some differences between .bashrc and .profile and when they go into effect.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** this is not a direct answer to what OP is asking, but it can be useful to solve it's problem, perhaps.

For already started processes, you can retrieve the start date/time issuing a simple `ps ax -F`. It will show an output similar to the following:

```
apache    1733  1678  0 83467  7752   0 10:07 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    1734  1678  0 83467  7752   0 10:07 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    1735  1678  0 83467  7752   0 10:07 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    1736  1678  0 83467  7768   0 10:07 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    1737  1678  0 83467  7752   0 10:07 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    1738  1678  0 83467  7752   0 10:07 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

As you can see, the 8th column show the start date/time.